# having your own backend for user management, how can we secure the access to a firestore db using flutter mobile?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have initially used this below, everything was working fine.
some days after I received an email for google saying my data can be seen by anybody.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write:  if true;
    }
  }
}
```

after some searchs, i found this :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write:  request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Just after modifying those rules, I have my own backend for authentification :

Error i keep receiving :

> Exception has occurred.
>
> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

Comment: I've run a similar issue. If you have your own backend for authentication, your authentication means nothing to Firebase. During your auth, your backend also needs to create a JWT for firebase (there are some SDKs for doing that), and that JWT needs to be sent back to your app, then your app needs to be configured to give that JWT to the Firebase SDK (the exact method is escaping me), so the requests can be authenticated by something that Firebase created / trusts.

The SDK is the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

As Jared commented, Firebase has no way to know that the user signed in to your backend, unless you tell it about it. This is known as custom authentication in Firebase, or building a custom provider for Firebase Authentication.

The process consists of:

1. Gathering the user's credentials and signing them in on your system.
2. In a trusted environment then [minting a Firebase Authentication token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) for that user, and passing that back to the client.
3. [Signing in to Firebase with the custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) (also see [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients)).

Comment: finally understood  the php code provided on Firebase website, my issue is sorted.